# iPhone - Center UIImage in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView.  I get a UIImage from a URL.  The image displays in the UIImageView, but I can't get it to center correctly.  The UIImage is 80 x 68 pixels.  The UIImaveView's size is 90 x 90.  When I display the UIImage in the UIImageView the UIImage is shrunken so that it fits, although it is already smaller than the UIImageView.  I have tried all the Content Modes in IB.  Some of them shift the image up so that it is no longer in the UIImageView.  None of this really makes sense to me.  It seems that the UIImage should display inside the UIImageView fine if it is already within the required size.  Any help would be great.

With Mode of Center on the UIImageView
[alt text http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/3696/screenshot20090915at447.png](http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/3696/screenshot20090915at447.png)

With Mode of Aspect Fit on the UIImageView
[alt text http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/9373/screenshot20090915at447e.png](http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/9373/screenshot20090915at447e.png)

With Center, the size of the image seems correct but you can see that it goes out of the UIImageView which has a red UIView underneath it and is actually 2px on each side larger than the image view.  But with the Aspect Fit, it makes the image smaller so that it fits inside.  But I don't understand why it would make it smaller if it is already small enough to fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for wasting anyone's time.  Turns out I didn't try all of the content modes.  Seems that  Content Mode of Bottom top works.  This is backwards from how I understood it.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Change your `UIImageView` to be the same size as the `UIImage` that you are going to load, then position the `UIImageView` so that it's centered.  This is the approach I've taken since I find `UIImageView` to be a bit funny to work with.  Or, if you prefer, skip the `UIImageView` and just draw the `UIImage` using it's `- (void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect` method.

Comment: Do you know any good examples of using drawInRect.  I haven't done anything with drawing on the iPhone.  I'm looking for examples, but if you know of any, that would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your image contains transparent areas, at least at the bottom, which shift the image off center.

Edit: Also, you should check that the resolution of the image is set to 72dpi.

Comment: So PNG images are great for allow the background to show through, but screw up the UIImageView alignment?  Interesting.  Is there a way to tell it to ignore the transparency or to fix this issue?

Comment: They do not screw up the alignment. The PNG has a clearly defined size in pixels (of course also counting transparent pixels). One simple solution would be to add the same (transparent) border at all sides.

Comment: I understand that PNG's can have transparent pixels, and the images I am using, do have this issue.  But what I am seeing is that an image with a size of 80 x 60 px is not properly placed into the UIImageView which has a size of 90 x 90.  Maybe centered was the wrong word.  The image, although smaller than the UIImageView, is moved up in the image view and actually spills out the top.  Basically what happens is that the bottom of the image is in the middle of the UIImageView which then forces the top of the image to be outside ( above ) the image view by several pixels.