# iPad displays image to big - but shouldn't

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I develop application for iPad 3 - with Retina display. I calculated, based on specification, that image should be 1536 x 2008 to fill (with a statusbar) entire screen. I resized image to such dimensions, and I programmatically load it and sets it to display on UIImageView (loaded from storyboard). What is more, to get best performance I set up UIImageView mode to Center (to avoid scaling). When I run app I see only center of my image - as if my image was 4 times the screen - which is not true.

Hers my code of viewWillAppear method

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: self.pageData.pageFilename];

NSLog(@"Image size: %f %f", [image size].width, [image size].height);

NSLog(@"Image view size: %f %f", self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height);

[ self.imageView setImage: image];
```

And I get in output:

```
Image size: 1536.000000 1990.000000
Image view size: 768.000000 1004.000000
```

How to correct this? My image is JPG with size you can see, and 72 DPI - but I'm sure that DPI doesn't matter

Comment: Have you tested with any of the other modes? (just for debugging purpouses) - The user of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428816/iphone-center-uiimage-in-uiimageview also used 'center' with sort of the same behavior (bottom-top) worked in his case.

Comment: the `UIImage` size is in **pixels** the `UIImageView` size is in **points**. what is problem exactly? the two units are different from each other.

Comment: what is _exact_ name of your image? have you fitted the `@2x` extension after the name?

Comment: @holex: no. My image have no `@2x` - as it will be downloaded from Internet in final version. I thought then `@2x` applies only to bundled resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing up pixel and points.

In iOS dimensions are measured in points, not in pixles. If the device uses retina display, then 1 point = 2 pixel. Using the old display you have 1 point = 1 pixel.

---

**Normal display**
1 point = 1 pixel
1024 * 768 points
1024 * 768 pixel

**Retina display**
1 point = 2 pixel
1024 * 768 points
2048 * 1536 pixel

---

So in both cases the size of the display has the same size:
**1024 * 768 points**

Comment: OK, you are right. However then, how to take full advantage of Retina display? My picture is near the size you given (1990x1536) and therefore should fit the screen perfectly.